# Unable to cast object of type X to type X

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception, vs-web-site-project

Users randomly get "Unable to cast object of type "X" to type "X" exception error. Sometimes this issue will happen a few times a day. Sometime we can go a week+ w/o it coming up.

I have an serialized object ("X") that I populate in a list "CurrentDetails" & "NextDetails" as "X". On a text change event, I check for a value in "CurrentDetails" at which point the exception fires. "Unable to cast object of type X to type X" Here are a few code samples...

Text Change Event (Edited to show raw data)

```
Protected Sub txtPackaging_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtPackaging.TextChanged
    If WarehouseManager.GetDeliveryStatus(CurrentSUPPDelivery.DeliveryNumber) > 60 Then
        'GETTIGN ERROR HERE Unable to cast object of type 'SUPPDelivery' to type 'SUPPDelivery' 
        'THROW ERROR
        SetErrorMessage("<b>REFRESH/BACK DETECTED!</b> <br/> Or, this item has already been packed. <br/> Please exit wave.")
        pnlItemDetails.Visible = False
        pnlCurrent.Visible = False
        pnlWaveDetails.Visible = False
    Else 'continue pick/pack
        btnProcessSingleItem_Click(sender, e)

    End If

End Sub
```

View State Object (Edited to show raw data)

```
Private Property CurrentSUPPDelivery() As WarehouseManager.SUPPDelivery
    Get
        Return Me.ViewState("CurrentSUPPDelivery")
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As WarehouseManager.SUPPDelivery)
        Me.ViewState("CurrentSUPPDelivery") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

It is throwing an error on the IF statement of the txtChange event. Any ideas?

EDIT: Raw Stack Data....

> Stack trace: at Warehouse_SingleUnitPickPack.get_CurrentSUPPDelivery()
>   in
>   C:\Inetpub\lawsonwebapps\warehouse\mobile\SingleUnitPickPack.aspx.vb:line
>   107 at Warehouse_SingleUnitPickPack.txtPackaging_TextChanged(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Inetpub\lawsonwebapps\warehouse\mobile\SingleUnitPickPack.aspx.vb:line
>   249 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.OnTextChanged(EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.RaisePostDataChangedEvent() at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.RaisePostDataChangedEvent()
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaiseChangedEvents() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

EDIT: "X" - Manager.CurrentDetails ... RAW Name:SUPPDelivery

```
<Serializable()> Public Class SUPPDelivery

        Private _DeliveryNumber As String
        Private _OrderNumber As String
        Private _OrderLine As String
        Private _TransactionType As String
        Private _PackedQty As String
        Private _PackageNumber As String
        Private _PackageMaterial As String
        Private _OrderLineSuffix As String
        Private _ItemNumber As String
        Private _ItemLocation As String

        Public Property DeliveryNumber() As String
            Get
                Return _DeliveryNumber
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _DeliveryNumber = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property OrderNumber() As String
            Get
                Return _OrderNumber
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _OrderNumber = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property OrderLine() As String
            Get
                Return _OrderLine
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _OrderLine = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property TransactionType() As String
            Get
                Return _TransactionType
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _TransactionType = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property PackedQty() As String
            Get
                Return _PackedQty
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _PackedQty = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property PackageNumber() As String
            Get
                Return _PackageNumber
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _PackageNumber = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property PackageMaterial() As String
            Get
                Return _PackageMaterial
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _PackageMaterial = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property OrderLineSuffix() As String
            Get
                Return _OrderLineSuffix
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _OrderLineSuffix = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property ItemNumber() As String
            Get
                Return _ItemNumber
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _ItemNumber = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property ItemLocation() As String
            Get
                Return _ItemLocation
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _ItemLocation = value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class
```

Comment: Can you see the call stack?  If not, I'd fix your application so that it displays or logs the call stack when the exception occurs.  That will go a long way towards helping you solve what's happening.

Comment: There may be two different `X` types with the same name. Are the servers restarting? Is anything being redeployed? Is there a rogue server running a different version? Is the type `X` in a strongly-named assembly? Is the assembly version number updated on changes? Is `X` defined in a dynamically compiled code?

Comment: Your setter has a trailing whitespace - is that in your code?  `Me.ViewState("CurrentDetails ")`.  You've also given a property and a type the same name - could the compiler be having trouble with this?  It would help to see what `Manager.GetSomething` looks like, as would a call stack help and knowing what `.TheSomething` is.

Comment: Yes, i have the stack, i updated it, but its the 'raw' data so some of the the stuff is different from my example above.

Comment: @pst - there is only one object called "SUPPDelivery" ("X") in the above example. This is for our intranet application for a small business so there is only 1 server. I'm assuming that is strongly-named. As that should be any reserved keywords. Also, i'm not sure what you mean about versions. I populate that data. Use it once, and clear it out. Then its populated with "NextDetails", if its not empty. I'm not sure what you mean by 'dynamically compiled code'? I'm sort of new at this... But wouldn't all Objects be dynamically compiled??? (hopefully this helps u help me) :)

Comment: @J... good catch, i was really hoping you were on to something there, but no. That was just me trying to simplify my code. Also the Manager.GetSomething is a simple select statement getting an integer by record number. I'm passing it the record number via the object, and that is whats blowing up. Its like the object loses what it is.

Comment: @JoshuaHarris could you be more specific?  Show us the type definition of `Manager.CurrentDetails` along with the method signature of `Manager.GetSomething`.  Is the property `CurrentDetails` a property of `Manager` or is it a property of something else which references the `Manager` class?

Comment: @J... I'm not sure what you mean by method signature, and the app is crashing before Manager.GetSomething is being called. That function requires a parameter and pulling that view-state parameter is what is crashing. But if you tell me what method signature is, i'll certainly post it. Manager.CurrentDEtails in the raw data is called SUPPDelivery, which is shown in the stack trace. I'll edit the post to show what is in the serialized object named "SUPPDelivery"

Comment: @JoshuaHarris - you've posted a class full of `string` properties. Where is the one with `Private Property CurrentDetails () As Manager.CurrentDetails`?  What is a `Manager.CurrentDetails`?  A method signature is the declaration line for a procedure or function - the line that gives the function name and the list of arguments it takes.  What does that line look like for `Manager.GetSomething`?  `Public\Private Sub\Function GetSomething(ByVal arg as ??)`

Comment: In general, I have seen this happen many times over the years during AppDomain transitions. You have an object of type `X` stored in session state or something, but your code is running in a new AppDomain, and `X` is now a different type, even if it has the same name. Find out whether there were any changes to the application at about that time. Check the IIS and Windows event logs.

Comment: @J... I don't have a private property. Manager.CurrentDetails is CurrentSUPPDelivery .... (See above) CurrentSUPPDelivery is serialized object named "SUPPDelivery" ... I have a list (2) "SUPPDelivery" one named "current" (above) and the other "next". Next works w/o issue. From what I can tell the app crashes here ' If WarehouseManager.GetDeliveryStatus(CurrentSUPPDelivery.DeliveryNumber) > 60 Then' on the '.get_CurrentSUPPDelivery()' I've edited above to include raw data. Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - good idea. Unfortunately we don't have any build system here, so i can't check any logs to see when new stuff was pushed live. But i will certainly keep any eye on it in the future.

Comment: There should be something in the event log. Do you have [ASP.NET Health Monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933.aspx) turned on? There's are events for AppDomain restarts.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - you seem to be on to something here... 

Anytime the site recomplies the "X" as "X" ... 'looses itself'? anyway to prevent this?

Comment: Are you using a web site "project"? If so, then the solution is to "not do that". If you weren't recompiling while your users were using the site, then you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - u r correct. We are using a web site "project". The issue is we have to be able to recompile. Is there another object type or something else I can use. Perhaps using cookies somehow? Any idea?

Comment: I never use web site "projects", as they are very strange, and are unique for no good reason.

Comment: @JohnSaunders i've even tried putting a key in a hidden field and tried to re-populate the object w/ the key, but it still crashes. i'm assuming it crashes because it doesn't know what the already loaded information is..... I guess thats what i'm trying to figure out at this point. 

What exactly causes this error and if i can try to re-populate the object or even clear it out. I've even did a try catch and it still errors out. (I could have try/catch on the wrong line thou)